# Is there an app for iOS that can create split zip or rar files?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, archive

I'm looking for an app for iOS that can create a split zip or rar file. For example, instead of creating one big zip file (e.g. test.zip, 90 MB), it would create two smaller zip files (e.g. test.zip.001, 50 MB and test.zip.002, 40 MB).

On Android, such an app would be [ZArchiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.zdevs.zarchiver).

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Comment: I wonder if Pythonista would import this module https://pypi.org/project/filesplit/